# Mongoose post 'findOneAndUpdate' hook 'this' is empty object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

The [Mongoose Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) state that `findOneAndUpdate` pre/post hooks operate on the query rather than the document, which I (think I) understand.

I have a pre/post hook for `findOneAndUpdate` (it doesn't matter if it's pre or post, it doesn't work either way) like this:

```js
bookSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async () => {
    const docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery());
    // this.set({'modified.by': 'req.user.id', 'modified.at': Date.now()})
    docToUpdate.modified.by = req.user.id;
    docToUpdate.modified.at = Date.now();
    await docToUpdate.save();
});
```

The issue I'm running into is that `this` within the hook is an empty object `{}` at runtime, rather than the query object.

Here's my query: `const currentBook = await Book.findOneAndUpdate({id: req.params.bookId}, req.body);`

As far as I can tell, the query works and updates the information correctly, the hook just doesn't seem to have access to `this`

Answer (score 2):

`this` is an empty object because you use arrow function instead of regular, anonymous function.

Change to:

```
bookSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next) {
    const docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery());
    // this.set({'modified.by': 'req.user.id', 'modified.at': Date.now()})
    docToUpdate.modified.by = req.user.id;
    docToUpdate.modified.at = Date.now();
    await docToUpdate.save();
    next();
});
```

and `this` will be what you've expected.